# Inequality with Force of interest

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, inequality

I have to show the following inequalities and don't know how to proceed:

If $t \geq 0$, then show

$$ d \leq d_m \leq \delta \leq r_m \leq r \text{ for } m \geq 1$$

where $\delta$ is the force of interest, $r$ the annual effective interest rate, $r_m$ the nominal interest rate, convertible m times per year, $d$ the annual effective discount rate and $d_m$ the equivalent nominal rate of interest in advance credited $m$ times per year.

So I know that $r = (1+ \frac{r_m}{m})^m -1 \geq 1 + m \cdot \frac{r_m}{m} -1 = r_m$ follows by Bernoulli. Any suggestions on how to proceed now? I know that $$\delta = \lim_{m \to \infty} r_m = \lim_{m \to \infty} d_m$$

Furthermore, $d = 1-(1-\frac{d_m}{m})^m$ and $d_m = m(1-(1-d)^{\frac{1}{m}})$. How can I show know the inequality $d \leq d_m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $d\leq d_m\leq \delta$, fix $0<d<1$ and observe that 
$$
d_m= \frac{1-(1-d)^{\frac1m}}{\frac1m}, \ \ \ \  d_1=d.
$$
Now, let $g(x)=(1-d)^x$. We have $g(0)=1$ and 
$$
d_m=\frac{g(0)-g(\frac1m)}{\frac1m}= - \frac{g(\frac1m)-g(0)}{\frac1m}.
$$
Since $g(x)$ is a decreasing convex function in $x$,  we see that $d_m$ is increasing as $m$ increases. Moreover, 
$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} d_m = -\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x} = -\ln (1-d)=\delta.$$
Therefore, we have $d_m\leq \delta$.

A similar approach works for $r_m$ as well.

For the other question about $r_m-d_n < \frac{r^2}{\min(m,n)}$, write $k=\min(m,n)$ and
$$
r_m-d_n\leq r_k-d_k = k((1+r)^{\frac1k}-1 - 1 + (1-d)^{\frac1k})=k((1+r)^{\frac1k}+(1+r)^{-\frac1k}-2).
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align}
k((1+r)^{\frac1k}+(1+r)^{-\frac1k}-2)&= \frac k{(1+r)^{\frac1k}}\left( (1+r)^{\frac1k} - 1 \right)^2 \\
&=\frac {k r^2}{(1+r)^{\frac1k} \left( 1+(1+r)^{\frac1k} + (1+r)^{\frac2k} + \cdots + (1+r)^{\frac{k-1}k} \right)^2 }\\
& < \frac{ kr^2} {k^2} = \frac {r^2}k = \frac{ r^2}{\min(m,n)}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why is $f'(d) \leq 0$? Isn't $0< (1-d)^{\frac{1-m}{m}} <1$ and therefore $0 < 1- (1-d)^{\frac{1-m}{m}} <1$ and therefore the whole term is $\geq 0$? Then $f$ would be increasing o $0<d<1$, $f(0))=\frac{1}{m}$ and therefore $f(d) \leq 1)$?

Comment: Another question to the other inequalities $d_m \leq \delta \leq r_m$: Is it possible to say that since $\lim r_m = \delta$ and $r_m$ is monotone decreasing, the limit $\delta$ has to be $\leq r_m$. Also $d_m = \frac{r_m}{1+\frac{r_m}{m}}$ and therefore $\lim d_m = \delta$ and since $d_m$ is increasing, $d_m \leq delta$..?

Comment: Since $1-m\leq 0$, we have $f'(d)\leq 0$.

Comment: I will work on your second question in a few hours.

Comment: Okay I get it know. Thank you for your help and for your help ´with the further question!

Comment: The first argument was unnecessarily long indeed. I figured that the proof for second one implies the first inequality too.

Comment: Which inequalites do you mean?

Comment: I just saw the edit, so ignore the last question...but just for my better understanding: I can show that the function $g$ is decreasing via differntiating. How can I proof that $d_m$ is increasing then? For $r_m$ I've tried the same with the function $g(x) = (1+r)^x$ and got to the same result. But again I have here the question how can i formally proof, that $r_m$ is decreasing then? And another question: Is it possible to extend the chain of inequalities to $<$ if I replace the condition to $r > 0$ with the same proof?

Comment: To prove that $d_m$ is increasing or $r_m$ is decreasing, we need that $g(x) = (1-d)^x$ is convex, and $h(x) = (1+r)^x$ is convex. Also, use that $1/m$ is decreasing toward $0$. Drawing graphs of $g$ and $h$ will help.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any formal proof of showing that i.e. $d_m$ is increasing? I've tried now another proof for the following: If $r>0$, then $d<d_2<d_3< \cdots < \delta < \cdots < r_3<r_2<r$ holds. Do you maybe know now, how it is possible to show the following inequality: $$r_m - d_n < \frac{r^2}{\min(m,n) \text{ for } m,n \in \mathbb{N}$$? I've thought of using the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means but don't know how to proceed..

Comment: I think the proof is sufficiently formal. I left out some details, which include the following: If $f$ is a convex function and $a<b<c$ then $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}.$$ This one can be done by using definition of convex.

Comment: For your other question, what you want to prove is not clear because of latex error.

Comment: Sorry, the other question was: If I show for $r>0$ that $d<d_2<d_3<\cdots<\delta<\cdots<r_3<r_2<r$ holds, how can i prove the following inequality: $r_m-d_n < \frac{r^2}{\min(m,n)}$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Can you explain me, what happens in the last step before $ < \frac{k r^2}{k^2}$, i.e. the last equality, and maybe also the inequality afterwards?

Comment: Probably it is somehow a geometrical sum I guess

Comment: Okay I got it, thank you for your help though :D

Comment: Glad it helped. If you find this answer helpful, you can upvote and accept it. By doing so, it encourages the writer of answers very much.